# Android automatich Touch Event

Tags: android, touch-event

When a touch_down is detected in android, a touch_up is automatically fired after a while (the time is depending on the hardware)
I guess this is for security reason.
In my app, on touch_up events, some actions are done, and I would like NOT to do them on these  automatic touch_up events.

Do you know :
- if it is possible to get rid of them (the OS not sending them to my view) ?
- or do you have an idea to detect that an action_up is from this kind (automatic) and not actually from the user really lifting his finger ?

thanks

Comment: While it is certainly possible that some devices do this, I have experienced no such thing and I happen to have several android devices from many manufacturers. Do you have any documentation on this?

Comment: thanks for your answer. i dont have any doc on this.but if you try the multitouch tester on google play you will experience this. just press the screen and wait for 20 seconds or so.i have a motorola xoom

Comment: Oh, believe me. This isn't an answer... just a comment. I wrote a custom launcher that does perpetual touch sensing. After reading this question, I tested it on all of my devices for up to 2 minutes and got no such result. Are you sure its not simply implemented that way in the tester app? Maybe one of the fantastic experts here can elaborate on this?

Comment: ok, then it gives me hope !
The thing is that I just logged the received events, without any treatment at all and I get this touch_up from the OS. If you don't experience this, it either comes from your devices that don't send the event, or you coded somthing to prevent it to happen (but tyou would know :) )

Comment: another example using the os itself : pressan icon on the screen. it becomes highlighted so that you canmove it. if you wait for 20 secondz or so, the icon becomes unselected again ...

Comment: Are you sure that it is not do to touch point moving. I know that some apps do not implement the TouchSlop leading to behavior like you are seeing... Again, I'm not saying you are incorrect; I'm playing devil's advocate because *I* haven't seen the behavior. (TouchSlop is a factor by which you determine whether the touch point has moved or not, but you have to implement it in order to use it).

Comment: can you tell me if you have the same behaviour when pressing an icon from the android desktop and waiting for a while? this is not something i coded my self :) andtherefore we would have the answer wether ornotthisis a general behaviour in android or if this is device dependant. thanks!

Comment: nobody with the same behavior on his device (mine is a motorola xoom) concerning a long press on an icon from the main screen getting canceled after 20 secs ?

Comment: Not on mine? I have several devices. But... there might be a way to find out for sure. There was an app that I used to use to determine the touch capabilities of the device. I'd have to see if I could find it.

Comment: i tried on other devices as well and i could NOT reproduce the problem. there is definitely something different with the motorola xoom. i will investigate by asking the motorola guys what is going on !

Comment: I can reproduce this on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.  To me this is a major issue that prevents implementation of any feature in a app that requires the user hold down a button on the screen for > 20 seconds.  I am yet to find a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFter discussion with a developer from Motorola, the problem comes from Motorola.
They implemented something on top of the android framework to prevent touch event to be stuck. ...
There is nothing that can be done about that ...